# A very long time of loading data. Large Amount of Data. SQL queries in C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oledb

I have the following code in C# WPF

```
ConsultaDB consulta = new ConsultaDB();
foreach (var item in lista)
{
    var cp = consulta.returnCP(item.Key);
    if (cp.Length != 5)
    {
        //Some code here with the data returned
    }
}
```

`list` is a collection of >100K elements, and the `ConsultaDB` object have the following code:

```
class ConsultaDB
{
    string CP;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CCPP.accdb");
    public string returnCP(string id)
    {
        var comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT CP FROM CP WHERE ID='" + id+ "'";
        var returnValue = comm.ExecuteScalar();
        CP = returnValue.ToString();
        return CP;
    }

    public ConsultaDB()
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
}
```

The problem here is that all that requests to the DB consume a large amount of time to be completed. I saw that the loop is working well, but for sure is not optimized.

So, how can I improve the speed of that process?

Comment: For starters you can use `where id in (1,3,5,7,8,9)` and do you really need to select all 100k? And if you had the IDs in your DB - you could do a join which would be way faster.

Comment: @juergen-d The DB has pairs id,CP. I need to know the CP of every element of my list to make statistic calculations.

Comment: And where do the IDs in your code come from? If from the DB too then you can load the CPs directly

Comment: @juergen-d I read from a file the IDs to analyze and I made a dictionary with it. Then, I want to know the CP associated to every ID in that file. There're aprox 120K IDs.

Comment: You can *cache* the results acquired in a cache in order to not ask RDBMS for them again; or even you can cache the whole `CP` table in a dictionary

Comment: Then why not instead load the IDs from file into the DB and then do a join there. Or if memory usage is not the issue and loading the complete table into your program is possible, then what @gnqz answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try caching the whole `CP` table in a dictionary:

```
class ConsultaDB {
  private static Dictionary<String, String> s_Data = new
    Dictionary<String, String>();

  private static void CoreFeedCache() {
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CCPP.accdb")) {
      using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        comm.CommandText = 
          @"select ID,
                   CP
              from CP";

        using (reader = comm.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read()) {
            s_Data.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0]), Convert.ToString(reader[1]));
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  } 

  static {
    CoreFeedCache();
  }

  public static string returnCP(string id) {
    String result;

    if (!s_Data.TryGetValue(id, out result))
      result = null;

    return result;
  } 
}
```

If `CP` has about *100K* items as well, it  will require *MegaBytes* of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting the CPs one by one, do a single query, which selects the whole table and then iterate in table. It will greatly improve the speed.
Your query will be:

```
"SELECT * FROM CP";
```

Then do something like:

```
 List<string> cps = table_name.AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(r=> r.Field<string>("...."))
                           .ToList();
```

An advice from a guy who has played quite a lot with Access DBs - always use parametrized queries. It will save you most of the incompatible type errors. Especially when you work with dates...

Answer (score 1):

1. Get more data at once - since you know list of ids in advance, instead of querying item one by one do one call. If you want items with keys `(1,2,3,4)` then instead of doing 4 queries just execute one

   ```
   SELECT CP FROM CP WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4)
   ```

   In `C#` code this would mean

   ```
   public string returnCP(List<string> ids)
       {
           var comm = conn.CreateCommand();
           comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           comm.CommandText = string.Format( "SELECT CP FROM CP WHERE ID IN({0})",string.Join(",",ids));
           var returnValue = comm.ExecuteScalar();
           CP = returnValue.ToString();
           return CP;
       }
   ```
2. Page requests if you need a lot of ids. In case you need 10,000 ids it would be inefficient to load all of them at once - it's better to split data requests in several small pieces. So that they still load couple of hundred records but not too much.
3. If data access is still a bottleneck and you call it frequently for the same objects consider using *cache* - it will allow you to access data faster. Depending on your architecture in-memory cache can make data access blazingly fast.
4. This is very case-specific but if `CP` is not unique (read : it's often the same for many records) you may as well use `GROUP` query

   ```
   SELECT CP,COUNT(*) FROM CP GROUP BY CP
   ```

   In this way you obtain `CP` values with counts which should reduce amount of data
5. Please read about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to make your code more secure

Comment: I think that I'm going to cache the table into a dictionary as @dmitry-bychenko suggested, thanks for your great answer!

Comment: @FernandoGallegoFernández thank you , I'm glad I could help. Also, feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**Modified :**

```
var strId=string.empty;
lista.Foreach(x=>
{
strId+=","+x.itemKey;
});
var cp = consulta.returnCP(strId=strId.TrimStart(','));
```

So this will pass all the id as comma seperated, to the function and it will executed only once the SQL query and hence the Database connection will be opened only once. The rest of the Logic should be inserted inside a Stored procedure, As the SP is again much faster than that of the normal SQL query. 90% of the time will be saved. Hope this works.